# Why does the SE Web app and Android app display different scores for Tags?

Tags: discussion, android-app, tag-score

How come the Android app displays total score for tags, whereas the Web App displays total score for answers (SO & Politics.SE)?

Web: 
[image]

Android:
[image]

This isn't a question regarding the calculation of score, but rather the display of the score. Wouldn't it be more consistent to have the same parameters for both platforms? (i.e. just display answer scores or just display total scores)

Comment: @rene The scores are not wrong, they just don't display the same scores. i.e. answers scores on both, or total score on both.

Comment: Isn't that what the accepted answer says: they show different things?

Comment: my apologies, you're right. I still don't get why they've done it though. my pedantic tendencies are going crazy.

Comment: @BradleyWilson read the last paragraph in balpha's answer. (tl;dr - since app got no tooltip.)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @ShadowWizard + rene, you'd think after three years an alternative would show up.

Comment: What do you mean by alternative? To tooltips in general? That's not on SE control... (e.g. personally I can imagine a future where the mobile device will detect where exactly you're looking at, and show a tooltip based on that.)

Comment: Oh no, i mean a general workaround (disregarding tooltips) for example: display the total on the web version as well as the answers total to avoid further confusion differentiating the score between apps .